# How to read WinRT errors?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, uwp

While debugging my Universal Windows Application in the Visual Studio 2015 I noticed some errors in the output window:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE25967788 (KernelBase.dll) in xxx.exe: 0x40080201: WinRT originate error (parameters: 0x0000000080072738, 0x00000000000000C2, 0x000000217DCFEFD0).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE25967788 (KernelBase.dll) in xxx.exe: 0xE06D7363: Microsoft C++ Exception (parameters: 0xCCCCCCCC19930520, 0x000000217D6FD410, 0x00007FFE08A58AD0, 0x00007FFE08980000).
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFE25967788 (KernelBase.dll) in xxx.exe: 0x40080202: WinRT transform error (parameters: 0x0000000080072738, 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000027, 0x000000217D6FEF90).
```

The problem is that I do not know how to read these errors. What is the meaning of these codes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is just noise, the kind that the debugger can't avoid producing since it always gets a "first chance" notification for exceptions.  WinRT itself was written in C++ code and uses SEH exceptions to get its job done.  Such exceptions by COM rules are not allowed to cross a module boundary and they are caught in the WinRT code.  They *may* produce an error code for an api call that gets re-raised in your own program but that is not necessarily the case.  Looks like they didn't so ignore.

If you want to do some more digging to see the soul of the machine then [this blog post](http://www.jonathanantoine.com/2015/07/25/winrt-exceptions-how-to-know-what-the-hexadecimal-error-code-means/) gives decent hints.